# VSFTP lost root access

Tags: vsftpd

I created an FTP, using only my local username. The issue was that I had access to all files on the computer, until I decided to actually try to create one in /media/USER/HDD1

It gave me the error:
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()

So, I accidentally used the command:
chmod a-w /home/testuser

instead of:
‘allow_writeable_chroot=YES’ | sudo tee -append /etc/vsftpd.conf

Now, when I go to FileZilla, I have access only to the home folder on the FTP. How do I get back the access?

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find an answer to this, creating a mountpoint:

sudo mkdir /media/DISK1

then mounting it in the home directory:
sudo mount /sdb/sdb2 /home/USER/Disk1

seems to be doing the trick.